# How to insert an image into a post without linking to the attachment page

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I'm displaying the content in wordpress, I'm usint `the_content` inside of the loop and everything is working great, I get an image and the text of the post.

The only thing that I don't want is that the image link would take you to the attachment page, I want the user to be directed to post permalink.

Comment: I think you can edit this on the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the nature of the image inserted into the post via the Visual Editor. Click on the image, and select "Edit Image". Then, find the option for "image links to" (file, page, or none). Change from "page" to either "file" or "none".

Comment: I'm able to change the Title but Link URL doesn't save

Comment: How are you inserting the image into the post?

Comment: gallery so I upload 4/5 images at a time, it allows me to use enter: None, File URL, Attacchment Post URL but not custom URL... Maybe I need to create a new post and try this out again

Comment: Why do you need a custom URL? Just use **File URL** or **None**, if your goal is not to output a link to the Attachment Post.

Comment: File URL is: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/042.jpg, attachment post URL is: http://example.com/2012/11/26/title/04-3/ but I want URL link to: http://example.com/2012/11/26/title/

Comment: Okay, but "*linking to a custom URL*" is a different question from this one, which is titled, "*without linking to the attachment page*"

Comment: how to link to the post page?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the post and change the URL the image points to. You can do this by clicking the little edit icon when you click on the image.

Alternatively, remove the image link altogether.

Comment: I'm using the gallery, so i guess i can do it there